# Get only date and month from list column using CAML query

Tags: date, caml, monthcalendar

I created a list of birthdays with a column `Datetime` that stores birthdays of employee (e.g., 20/10/1994). I want to get the date and month from the column of a custom list.

I want to run a timer job whenever the current date is equal to the date of the column.

For that I need a CAML query that fetches a particular list item based on the current date and month.

Comment: I used eq condition with today date and it's not working..I am not clear in caml to fetch items based on only date and month..

Comment: @Pranav : qry.Query = "<Where><eq><FieldRef Name='BirthDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>"+ SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(System.DateTime.Now) +"</Value></eq></Where>";

Comment: But I am unable to fetch according to my requirement..can u try this..plz